# Laravel 6.x Set auth()->user() By Getting Current User From Axios Call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am working with a team where we have built an application that already has a user login authentication. It stores the current user's ID so that it can be called through calling:

```
axios.get('/user/getmyid')
    .then((response_ => {
        user_ID = response.data;
}
```

The application (built with Vue.JS, Vuex, and Vuetify, not Laravel) routes to my Laravel 6 application, which I have set up in such a way that it requires the use of auth()->id(). I want to be able to retrieve the user_ID and force Laravel's Authentication to Login as the user with that id. We are using the same table for users for both applications, but it isn't called 'users'. Instead, it is called 'User', which I am also having trouble with Laravel 6's Authentication, as Laravel Auth looks specifically for a table called 'users'.

How might I force Auth to 1) login is the user with that ID in Laravel 6, and 2) check against the table 'User' instead of looking for the default 'users' table?

I know that you used to be able to use something similar to the following to work around it in the LoginController():

```
public function postLogin() {
$user = User::where('USER_NAME', '=', Input::get('username'))->firstOrFail();
    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect('home');
}
```

However, this was a solution for Laravel 5.2 and no longer works.

Please help me, I am absolutely lost and no one seems to have found an answer.

Comment: Few things; First, `return redirect('home');` wouldn't work for an axios (API) call; it should return a `return response()->json(...);` response. Second, `users` is the default table because the model is call `User`, and Laravel guesses the table name from the model name (lower-case, plural). You can use `protected $table = "User";` to set the table in your `User` model, but that goes against naming conventions.

Comment: I'm not trying to make the axios call in this, I need to pass the data (the user_ID) I get from that call to this so that I can set the auth to login to the user with that ID. Also, trust me I know about the conventions. I originally made it with the correct conventions, but the other application's team members wrote their database with weird naming conventions and I unfortunately have to connect to it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a custom Authentication guard. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: @JosiahBell Completely understandable; I think I may have misunderstood what you're trying to do. At a first glance, if you're trying to login with the `user_id` returned from the axios call by submitting to `postLogin()`, `$request->input("username")` wouldn't be right; it would be `$request->input("user_id")` (or similar), and you'd query for the user based on `USER_ID`, not `USER_NAME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Here is how:

In my `app\User` model, I added:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_ID';
```

which then replaced the default Auth `$primaryKey` that was just `'id'`.

Then I added the following function to `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`:

```
public function postLogin($uid) {
        $user = User::where('user_ID', '=', $uid)->firstOrFail();

        auth()->loginUsingId($user->user_ID);

        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

In `routes\web` I added the following route **below** the rest of my routes:

```
Route::get('/{uid}', 'Auth\LoginController@postLogin');
```

And that solved my issue! I also had to customize the attributes in the `protected $fillable = [ ... ]` and `protected $hidden = [ ... ]` arrays in the `app\User` model so that they fit with the attributes of my users.

But this worked for me and I hope it helps others! Thank you to those who commented on my question, it really inspired me to dig deeper and figure it out!

Comment: Did you end up having to modify `protected $table = "User";`? I'm kinda surprised this would work without it! But glad you got it working regardless :)

Comment: Yes I did have to modify the `protected $table = 'User';` as well to get it to work. Otherwise it would have kept looking for a table called `'users'` that didn't exist.